# ArgParse @add_arg_table not recognized in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia v0.3.9 right now. I recently updated all my packages (I haven't opened Julia in a couple months), including ArgParse. The macro @add_arg_table isn't recognized though. In particular, I tried running example code [here](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/ArgParse.jl/blob/master/examples/argparse_example3.jl), but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: @add_arg_table not defined
   in include at /Applications/Julia-0.3.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib

   in include_from_node1 at /Applications/Julia-0.3.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib`
 while loading /Users/Uthsav/Desktop/Walking The Interactome Work/arg.jl, in expression starting on line 42
```

This is essentially the problem I'm having in my own code. I looked but couldn't find any information about this besides what it says on the Github, which is that the macro @add_arg_table should still work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question on multiple forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/i9r3VAh9wV8.

Comment: Again, sorry about that!

Comment: No worries; it's just the same people answering in various places.